# Why .last() & .after() changes the position of an element cloned in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying to clone an element and to position it next to the original element, maybe someone here who can help me out because i've been struggling with it for a while.. i use the add__button to make a new frame but it changes the position

Jquery

```
    _this.addClickFunction = function() {
  var i = 0;

  // $('.add__button').click(function() {

    _doc.on('click', '.add__button',function() {
      $('#storyboard .frame' ).last().after( $('<div class="frame"> '+ 
        '<div class="frame__outer"> '+
          '<div class="frame__inner"></div>'+
           '<div class="frame_content">'+
             '<div class="frame__titel">'+
               '<span><input id="text" placeholder="Titel" type="text" /></span>'+
              '</div>'+
              '<form>'+
                '<div class="frame__tekst">'+
                  '<textarea rows="10" cols="45" placeholder="Informatie"></textarea>'+
                  '</div>'+
              '</form>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>'));

  });
};
```

CSS

```
.add__button{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border: 2px dotted red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-left: 36px;
    display: inline-flex;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 50;
}
```

Some inimportant CSS

```
    #storyboard{
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.frame {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin:0px 40px 40px 0px;
}
.frame__outer{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border: 2px solid red;

}
.frame__inner{
    width: 296px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -1px rgba(210,210,210,1); 
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px !important;

}
.frame__content{
    width: 296px;
    height: 200px;


}
label {
    display: table-cell;
}
span {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 2px; 
}
#text {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
    background-color: white;
}
textarea{
    width: 98%;
    text-indent: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    line-height: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none !important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top: 2px dotted #ff5151 !important;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px !important;
    background-color: white;
}
input,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `changes position`?

Comment: @Justinas What i want is that the add__button becomes right next to it but it comes sloping bottom right, that is what i ment

Comment: Your question is confusing - in the comment you mention the add button, but in the question you mention the "cloned" element yet you don't appear to be cloning anything.   Can you create a code snippet or a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem and a clear description on what it's supposed to.

Comment: Please read this [mcve]

Comment: @freedomn-m
I'm sorry about the English,
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DennisOffinga/8bp7sgu6/
the click doesn't work.

What i mean is when i click on the empty frame with the '+' sign in it,
a new frame appears but the empty frame stays in that weird position like you see on the fiddle.

thank you for you're time

Comment: I removed `display:inline-flex` and used simple `float:left` then it was just a case of fixing the `padding-top` (plus added jquery to the fiddle and removed the extra js).  Otherwise, I'm not sure what's wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/8bp7sgu6/1/